# SQLException - Could not retrieve transation read-only status server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, amazon-rds, dropwizard

This question seems to be there all over the internet but without any concrete solution. I have given up trying various ways.

Could anyone help with a more concrete solution or a way to go about knowing more about the underlying issue?

A few of the insert queries on a few tables, seem to be failing with the following error:

```
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server [statement:"INSERT INTO TABLE ({FIELDS}) VALUES({VALUES})", located:"INSERT INTO TABLE ({FIELDS}) VALUES({VALUES})", rewritten:"/* TableDAO.save */ INSERT INTO TABLE ({FIELDS}) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.SQLStatement.internalExecute(SQLStatement.java:1338)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.Update.executeAndReturnGeneratedKeys(Update.java:82)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.UpdateHandler$1.value(UpdateHandler.java:56)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.UpdateHandler.invoke(UpdateHandler.java:79)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject.invoke(SqlObject.java:224)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject$3.intercept(SqlObject.java:133)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.CloseInternalDoNotUseThisClass$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$dd33673f.save(<generated>)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.zoomcar.services.inventory.core.impl.UtilizationManagerImpl.calculateUtilization(UtilizationManagerImpl.java:233)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.zoomcar.services.inventory.scheduler.jobs.UtilizationCalculationJob.execute(UtilizationCalculationJob.java:25)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:545)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:489)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2610)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2576)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkReadOnlySafeStatement(PreparedStatement.java:1082)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1102)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor20.invoke(Unknown Source)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.execute(Unknown Source)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at org.skife.jdbi.v2.SQLStatement.internalExecute(SQLStatement.java:1327)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    ... 10 common frames omitted
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 67,698,890 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 67,698,891 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:590)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:57)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983)
application-2020-01-30-3.log.gz:    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1936)
```

Application framework: Dropwizard

DB URL used: "jdbc:mysql://{domain-name}:{port}/{DB_NAME}?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"

DB Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Application uses Amazon RDS

Comment: mysql-connector-version is 6.0.6

Answer (score 0):

To *"know more about the underlying issue"*, look at the real error message, i.e. the last listed "Caused by", not the errors derived from it:

> **Caused by:** `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException`: The last packet successfully received from the server was 67,698,890 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 67,698,891 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. **You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.**

To find *"a more concrete solution"*, do what the error message said.

---

Always look at the last listed "Caused by" in a stacktrace when researching the cause of an error. This is why it's so important to always list the full stacktrace here on StackOverflow. Good job doing that.

Comment: As you can see, the property is already set in the JDBC url. Still the issue persists. 
Also increased the wait_timeout.Hence the question. Anything else I should look at?

Comment: @AnushaDasari Configure your connection pool to replace connections by reducing their time-to-live.